# Открыть балун кластера

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Как правильно обработать такую ситуацию:

Есть карта, с кучей объектов, все это кластеризуется, при клике на id какого либо объекта происходит перемещение на карте до этого объекта, далее зум и далее открытие балуна. Вроде все ок.

Но как быть когда карта увеличена до предела, а объекты имеют одинаковые координаты, соответственно эти объекты находятся в кластере и при клике на id объекта также открывается балун объекта, а надо чтобы открывался балун кластера с объектами этого кластера.

должен помочь getObjectState(id) но метод возвращает неправильную инфу когда одинаковые координаты и в кластере.

```
        $(".lll").bind('click', function () {

            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

            var objectState = objectManager.getObjectState(id);

            //console.log(objectState);

            if (objectState.isClustered) {
                myMap.setCenter(objectManager.objects.getById(id).geometry.coordinates, 15, {checkZoomRange: true}).then(function () {
                    objectManager.objects.balloon.open(id);
                    //objectManager.clusters.state.set('activeObject', objectManager.objects.getById(id));
                    //objectManager.clusters.balloon.open(objectState.cluster.id);
                });
            } else {
                myMap.panTo(objectManager.objects.getById(id).geometry.coordinates).then(function () {
                    objectManager.objects.balloon.open(id);
                });
            }
        });
```

в общем вот мой пример:  https://jsfiddle.net/Agapkin/af32bxze/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Особенность в том, что если кластер за пределами видимой области карты, то он пропадает с карты и objectState.isClustered всегда равно false. Поэтому для того, чтобы ориентироваться на поле isClustered, нужно сначала поместить кластер в область видимости: https://jsfiddle.net/073yfgao/

```
myMap.setCenter(objectManager.objects.getById(id).geometry.coordinates, 15, {checkZoomRange: true}).then(function () {var objectState = objectManager.getObjectState(id);
            if (objectState.isClustered) {
                    objectManager.clusters.state.set('activeObject', objectManager.objects.getById(id));
                    objectManager.clusters.balloon.open(objectState.cluster.id);
            } else {
                    objectManager.objects.balloon.open(id);
            }
    });
});
```

Это то что вы хотели сделать?