# как показать объект кластера в objectManager? (раскластеризовать)

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть простой список названий объектов, доступный юзеру для клика. На карте нанесены все объекты, многие кластеризованы. Юзер кликает на ссылку, карта панорамируется к объекту, открывается балун объекта.

**Дополнено:** Объект при этом перекрашивается (меняет иконку).

Вопрос. Как раскластеризовать объект в objectManager (где кластеры только для чтения, то есть нельзя удалить его из кластера и положить просто на карту, как с плейсмарками)?

Зум работает плохо - не хочется всегда зумить на максимум. С другой стороны, если знать необходимый левел зума, при котором кластер раскластеризуется, то можно и так. Но как его узнать?

Также не хочется открывать групповой балун кластера, нужен индивидуальный. Но индивидуальный без раскластеризации открывается не в той позиции.

Comment: полагаю, вот тут решена как раз ваша задача: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/844542/273315

Comment: я видел, спасибо. Это открывает балун всего кластера, а надо - индивидуального объекта.

Comment: тамже есть пример, как открывать балун конкретного объекта

Comment: Чтобы получить индивидуальный объект, надо решить задачу раскластеризации (которая упирается, как вариант, в зум, но это костыли)

Comment: Вы знаете id объекта, на котором хотите открыть балун, вы можете это сделать независимо от того, находится ли объект в кластере методом `objectManager.objects.balloon.open(id);`. Просто метка останется меткой кластера, но по описанию задачи это и не важно, вам же только балун нужен.

Comment: Индивидуальный балун открывается в пустом пространстве, сбоку от кластера. Надо чтобы было на объекте.

Comment: Балун - дело второе (см. текст вопроса, последняя строка). Как быть со сменой иконки объекта? Дополню формулировку.